# google sheet api, write on any unused cell

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write to a google sheet from my Java application, using the API. The problem, as I see it, is that the API doesnt see the unused cells. So, if i try to write something on an empty cell, I am getting an error
This is what i tried to do

```
    URL cellFeedUrl1 = new URI(worksheets.get(0).getCellFeedUrl()+ "?min-row=20&max-row=20&min-col=1&max-col=1").toURL();
    CellFeed cellFeed1 =service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl1, CellFeed.class);
    CellEntry cell=  cellFeed1.getEntries().get(0);
    cell.changeInputValueLocal("200");
    cell.update();
```

This, since i have never used cell 20,1(A20 that is) will retun an emtpy list, causing a IndexOutOfBoundsException on `cellFeed1.getEntries().get(0);`

Is there a way to write to any cell on the sheet using the API?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `"?min-row=20&max-row=20&min-col=1&max-col=1"` in this line.

```
URL cellFeedUrl1 = new URI(worksheets.get(0).getCellFeedUrl()+ "?min-row=20&max-row=20&min-col=1&max-col=1").toURL();
```

To

```
URL cellFeedUrl1 = new URI(worksheets.get(0).getCellFeedUrl()).toURL();
```

Following the sample in this [document](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data#change_contents_of_a_cell).

Comment: yes, i have seen that, but it is using hash map. how could i write to one cell without using the map? is there a way?